# Get upvoted answers where question doesn’t have tag

Tags: support, answers, data-explorer

I want to get all of my upvoted answers where the question doesn’t have a specific tag.

What query can I write to get that data from SEDE?

For example, I want to get all my upvoted answers to posts that have not been tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need SEDE for this, the regular search is perfectly capable of this.

```
user:me is:a score:1 -[feature-request]
```

For me, that search query produces [the following results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aa+score%3A1+-%5Bfeature-request%5D):

[image]

---

Of course, it *can* be done in SEDE and it's a nice exercise. Here are some pointers:

- Join the `Posts` table with itself, the `ParentId` of the answer is the `Id` of the question
- Filter on the `OwnerUserId` of the answer. You can make this a parameter, so other users can use your query too, and I've written a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/8136/34061) to fill it automatically.
- Filter on the `Tags` of the question, i.e. `NOT LIKE '%<feature-request>%'`. Bonus points if you make that a parameter too. (Joining with `PostTags` and `Tags` is possible as well.)
- If you mean 'having a positive score' by 'upvoted', you can just filter on the `Score` of the answer. If you mean posts which received at least one upvote (and an arbitrary number of downvotes), you'd have to join with the `Votes` table and filter for votes with `VoteTypeId` equal to 2. Then you'd need a `DISTINCT` (or a `GROUP BY`) since you don't want an answer that is upvoted *n* times to appear *n* times in the results.

Comment: Thanks again, It works! I'll accept your answer in a moment...

Comment: ...6-8 moments later... @Jdrupal ;)

Comment: @ShadowTheBurningWizard HAHA, thanks for reminding me ;) #busyperson

Comment: I tried to create the query with the guidelines you gave, here it is https://data.stackexchange.com/drupal/query/1175827/get-upvoted-answers-where-question-doesnt-have-tag. It seems like it works fine, I just can't figure out how to add multiple tags to the tags input field.

Comment: Nice! You'd have to write a separate query, `NOT LIKE '%<' + @tag1 + '>%'` and `NOT LIKE '%<' + @tag2 + '>%'`. You could go fancy with `STRING_SPLIT` and a variable number of tags, but then you'd need joins with PostTags and Tags.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Thank you for helping me creating my first SEDE query!

Comment: You're welcome. For interactive help, you can always check if somebody is available  in the [SEDE chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223).

Comment: Thank's I'll do that in the future!